# Does a monster that saves against effect that gets reapplied by Dark Reach of Xevut get to save again?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, saving-throw, conditions

In response to a monster saving against a dominate effect at the end of its turn, I successfully hit with [Dark Reach of Xevut](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4189) and chose to apply the dominate back to the same monster as an immediate reaction.

According to the rules, should our DM allow the monster to save against the reapplied effect during the end of the same turn?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question, I'm not sure the text of the power allows for the reapplication of the condition to the same monster.

Answer (score 4):

No, they can't save again. The creature you choose with Dark Reach of Xevut "gains the effect that the target saved against." It doesn't give them a new effect, but the same effect.  The rules are clear: one saving throw per end of turn per effect.

**Compendium - Saving Throws:** (emphasis mine)

> If a creature is subject to an effect that a save can end, *the creature makes **a** saving throw against that effect at the end of each of its turns.* An effect that a save can end includes one of the following notations: “save ends,” “save ends both,” or “save ends all.”

Answer (score 3):

**No**, they cannot save again as Dark Reach of Xevut applies the effect to *another* enemy. The power's description says:

> One enemy within 3 squares of the target gains the effect that the target saved against.

This indicates an enemy distinct from the one that saved against the effect. Power descriptions are very explicit in who can be / is targeted by a power. The power states that the target is the triggering enemy; they take the 2d8 + Cha Mod Psychic damage on a hit and another enemy receives the effect. The flavor text says the "affliction" is transferred to a nearby foe.

Answer (score 1):

From the Rules Compendium p199

> The creature can choose the order in which things happen at the end of its turn.

So, yes, since the new save ends effect is on that creature, and it is still at the end of their turn, they can try to save against it.

You avoid this problem if you bounce the effect to a new target.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but it's worth mentioning that this makes the power roughly worthless against solos who are actually fighting solo (barring various save-triggers-cheese builds, naturally). Like many choices, GM style can render this one impotent.